# i get a Error : Input string was not a correct format with this code

Tags: vb.net, decimal

```
Private Sub ButtonComSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonComSave.Click
    Dim ComNamDis As String
    Dim ComPro1 As String
    Dim ComPro2 As String
    Dim ComPro3 As String
    Dim msg As MsgBoxResult

    If ButtonComSave.Text = "Save" Then
        ComNamDis = "Insert Into ComNamDis (Com_Code, Com_Name, Com_Discreption) Values(@Com_Code, @Com_Name, @Com_Discreption)"
        ComPro1 = "Insert Into ComPro (Com_Code, ComTyp, PriCat_Code, SubCat_Code, StoUni_Code, CalTyp_Code, CosTyp_Code, MiniW, MiniD, MiniH, MiniU, MiniQ, Local_Cost, "
        ComPro2 = "Last_Cost, Profit_Margin, Price) Values(@Com_Code, @ComTyp, @PriCat_Code, @SubCat_Code, @StoUni_Code, @CalTyp_Code, @CosTyp_Code, @MiniW, @MiniD, @MiniH, "
        ComPro3 = "@MiniU, @MiniQ, @Local_Cost, @Last_Cost, @Profit_Margin, @Price)"

        msg = MsgBox("You are sure to save this component ?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Confirm")
    Else
        ComNamDis = "Update ComNamDis set Com_Code = @Com_Code, Com_Name = @Com_Name, Com_Discreption = @Com_Discreption Where Com_Code = '" & txtComCod.Text & "'"
        ComPro1 = "Update ComPro set Com_Code = @Com_Code, ComTyp = @ComTyp, PriCat_Code = @PriCat_Code, SubCat_Code = @SubCat_Code, StoUni_Code = @StoUni_Code, "
        ComPro2 = "CalTyp_Code = @CalTyp_Code, CosTyp_Code = @CosTyp_Code, MiniW = @MiniW, MiniD = @MiniD, MiniH = @MiniH, MiniU = @MiniU, MiniQ = @MiniQ, "
        ComPro3 = "Local_Cost = @Local_Cost, Last_Cost = @Last_Cost, Profit_Margin = @Profit_Margin, Price = @Price Where Com_Code = '" & txtComCod.Text & "'"

        msg = MsgBox("You are sure to edit this component ?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Confirm")
    End If

    If msg = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

        Try
            Dim cmdComNamDis As New OleDbCommand(ComNamDis, Conn)

            cmdComNamDis.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Com_Code", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = txtComCod.Text
            cmdComNamDis.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Com_Name", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = txtComNam.Text
            cmdComNamDis.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Com_Discreption", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = txtComDis.Text

            Conn.Open()
            cmdComNamDis.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Dim cmdCompro As New OleDbCommand(ComPro1 & ComPro2 & ComPro3, Conn)

            cmdCompro.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Com_Code", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = txtComCod.Text
            cmdCompro.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@ComTyp", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = ComboBoxComTyp.Text
            cmdCompro.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@PriCat_Code", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = ComboBoxPriCat.ValueMember
            cmdCompro.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@SubCat_Code", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = ComboBoxSubCat.ValueMember
            cmdCompro.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@StoUni_Code", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = ComboBoxComStoUni.ValueMember
            cmdCompro.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@CalTyp_Code", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = ComboBoxComCalcolation.ValueMember
            cmdCompro.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@CosTyp_Code", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = ComboBoxComCostTyp.ValueMember

'i think here it's Problem
            cmdCompro.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@MiniW", OleDbType.Decimal)).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(txtComMiniW.Text)
            cmdCompro.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@MiniD", OleDbType.Decimal)).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(txtComMiniD.Text)
            cmdCompro.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@MiniH", OleDbType.Decimal)).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(txtComMiniH.Text)
            cmdCompro.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@MiniU", OleDbType.Decimal)).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(txtComMiniU.Text)
            cmdCompro.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@MiniQ", OleDbType.Decimal)).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(txtComMiniQ.Text)
            cmdCompro.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Local_Cost", OleDbType.Decimal)).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(txtComLocalCost.Text)
            cmdCompro.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Last_Cost", OleDbType.Decimal)).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(txtComLastCost.Text)
            cmdCompro.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Profit_Margin", OleDbType.Decimal)).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(txtComProfitMargin.Text)
            cmdCompro.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Price", OleDbType.Decimal)).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(txtComPrice.Text)

            cmdCompro.ExecuteNonQuery()

            If ButtonComSave.Text = "Save" Then
                MsgBox("The component has been saved successfully :) ", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Confirm")
            Else
                MsgBox("The component has been Edited successfully :) ", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Confirm")
            End If

            ButtonComNew_Click(sender, e)

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            Conn.Close()
        End Try
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The site shows you a preview of your question so maybe look at that before submitting to check that you haven't got a complete mess.

Comment: You could check that each entry is valid with the [`Decimal.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8) method before making the query.

Comment: You need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem, not just a wad of code. Why do you think the problem is there? What do you expect and what actually happens? What is the data in use at the time? If you know that the data is not a valid representation of a number then that's obviously the issue, so all the rest of the code is irrelevant. If the actual issue is validating user input then that's the question you should be asking.

Comment: How i can use Decimal.tryparse method to solved this pError

Comment: even if it works ... cmdCompro.ExecuteNonQuery() returns a value, that will inform you about the real result of the operation

Answer (score 0):

Connections and Commands need to be closed and disposed. Keep your connection objects local to method where the connection is used. Then you can use `Using...End Using` blocks to do the close, dispose.

Your validation could be done in the TextBox's Validating Event and use the ErrProvider. If you want to do it here in the Button.Click, do it at the beginning of the Sub.

```
Dim ComMiniW As Decimal
If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtComMiniW.Text, ComMiniW) Then
    MessageBox.Show("ComMinW must be a valid number")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

The down in the Parameters use the converted decimal variable.

```
cmdCompro.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@MiniW", OleDbType.Decimal)).Value = ComMiniW
```

Do this for each of the TextBoxes that require decimal values.